# Is there a way to save some frequently used text and paste inside code in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using a lot VScode for note-taking in Markdown and would be extremely useful to have a clipboard-like function to paste frequently used code inside the text. I mean that if I want to write some colored text I can paste with a keyboard shortcut the code `<span style="color:blue"> TEXT</span>`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at snippets, see  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets.  You could do something like this (in your snippets file):

```
 "markdown color" : {
    "prefix" : "mkColor",
    "body": [
        "<span style=\"color:${1:blue}\"> ${2:TEXT}</span>"
    ],
    "description": "Insert markdown span with color style"
  },
```

[image: markdown snippet demo]